# How to POST a request with the urlencode mode?

Tags: cypress, x-www-form-urlencoded

I'm a beginner with cypress, and I'm trying to send a POST request with mode urlencode to get the access token. This is script in postman:

```
  const postRequest = {
  url: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/967731f1/oauth2/v2.0/token',
  method: 'POST',
  header: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  },
  body: {
    mode: 'urlencoded',
    urlencoded:
    [
        {key: "client_id",value: "459e40d6-e96a-4c4e-833f-f43bd5d71885"},
        {key: "scope",value: "api://icy-beach-05c371d10.1.azurestaticapps.net/459e40d6-e96a-4c4e-833f-f43bd5d71885/access-as-user"},
        {key: "grant_type",value: "password"},
        {key: "username",value: "abc@gmail.com"},
        {key: "password",value: "xxxxxx"},
    ]
  }
};

pm.sendRequest(postRequest, (error, response) => {

  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

  pm.test('response should be okay to process', () => {
    pm.environment.set("accesstoken_admin", response.json().access_token);

  });

});
```

So, I do not know how to work on cypress. Does anyone help me? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
/// <reference types="cypress"/>
describe('login and create a new client',()=>{
    
        it('login by admin account',() => {
            cy.request({
                method: 'POST',
                url:'https://login.microsoftonline.com/967731f1/oauth2/v2.0/token',
                form: true,
                body: {
                        client_id: "459e40d6-e96a-4c4e-833f-f43bd5d71885",
                        scope: "api://icy-beach-05c371d10.1.azurestaticapps.net/459e40d6-e96a-4c4e-833f-f43bd5d71885/access-as-user",
                        grant_type: "password",
                        username: "abc@gmail.com",
                        password: "xxxxxx",
                }
                
            }).then((res) => {
                cy.log(JSON.stringify(res))
            })
        })
    })
```